# Excel - Error when using Column inside Indirect

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a couple of folders.
In my 'master' folder, I have 1000+ rows with 15 values, each.
In my 'auxiliary' folder, I have 66 rows with 15 values each. These 66 rows are updated by a macro (it works well).

I need to compute how many values each of those 66 'auxiliary' rows have, in common, with each of my 1000+ 'master' rows, but... I need all these 66 results (they will vary from 5 to 15, FYI) as cell values in my 'master' folder, after the 15 'key' values (Column `Q` onward).

Bottomline: I'm testing each 'master' row against 66 different 'auxiliary' rows and want the result (a single value, for each test) to be presented in 66 consecutive columns.

So, to avoid editing each of the 66 formulas to point to each of those 66 'auxiliary' rows, I decided to use `INDIRECT`.

Below, the code I'm using for each cell (`SOMARPRODUTO = SUMPRODUCT, CONT.SE = COUNT.IF, TEXTO = TEXT, INDIRETO = INDIRECT`, it's Portuguese):

```
=SOMARPRODUTO(CONT.SE(INDIRETO("Resultados!A"&TEXTO(LIN();"#")&":O"&TEXTO(LIN();"#"));INDIRETO(";Combinações!A"&TEXTO((COL()-12);"#")&":O"&TEXTO((COL()-12);"#"))))
```

... that gave me a round zero (`Q1`, in the image).

After some try and error I realized that whenever I use the `COL` function inside my second `INDIRECT` (the one that transposes the columns I need my values in to the lines that have to be checked) Excel looses it.

Does anybody have a solution for this (other than having all formulas explicitly written), or this is an Excel limitation/bug?

[image: Here is an image of my 'master' folder.]
Look at `Q3` and `Q4`. Both have text generated by code that should've been enough to feed the `INDIRECT` function.

`Q5` is working (that `10` is the correct result) but, just because I'm not using `COL` (the code is visible in the formula bar and was created to test the minus operation, `17-12`, (`17` is the result of `COL()`, for the `Q` column and would be used for the next 65 columns).

Thank you, in advance, for any answer.

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but is `LIN()` the function `ROW()`? If so, you don't neccessarly need to use the `TEXT`function and format the result into a number. It would also simplify the formula.

Comment: In Excel (although I am not 100% sure it is the same for the Portuguese version, but I cannot see why this would be different), the name of the worksheet (e.g. Combinações) must be between single quotation marks (but it seems to work for you without??). And I just use the `COL()` without the `TEXT` function. And in the formula in your question (not in the image you attached), you have a `;` before Combinações.

Comment: PS: I retract my comment about the single quotes around worksheet names; this is only necessary if there are spaces in the name.

Comment: You're right, @prextor. I noticed it and removed it, later... and, since INDIRECT is so finicky and resource consuming, I decided to create a transposed version of my 66 rows, in other folder, and reference them directly in my formula. I update the transposed in the same macro I update the rows.

Comment: Yes, @PeterK. , I removed that ';'... and then just gave up INDIRECT for this end. Thank you, all.

Comment: @AnJo888 Ok. But I still do not understand why your formula is not working. I tested it, and you can perfectly use `COLUMN()` within an `INDIRECT`. You probably know the `F9` trick to audit parts of formulas ?

Comment: Hey, @PeterK. No... I'm not aware of it... I, usually, copy parts of the code and try them in separate cells (as I did in 'Q3' and 'Q4'.
So, you're able to make that formula work, as it is?

Comment: @AnJo888 Yes, it worked for me with `COLUMN()`.   The `F9` trick (well, it is a normal, documented functionality in Excel, not a trick) is that you can, in the formula bar or in the cell itself, select a part of the formula (but the selection must be complete, i.e. no missing or too many parentheses), and tap `F9`, and your selection will be replaced by the intermediate result; you can do this several times to see in detail what happens in each step of the formula. Just don't forget to tap `ESC` to go back to the original/formula version.

Comment: Thank you, @PeterK.. I tested the F9 feature and it's quite useful.